# JS For Loop Inside a While Loop Returning Strange Results

Tags: javascript

I am trying to split a string and combine it based on its index.  A trivial example will be:

Input: "ABCABCABC"
Output: "AAABBBCCC"

So I created a function that converts the string into an array pops off the elements into its appropriate array and hopefully combine it back to a string.

Here's the function:

```
function splitter(string, numSplit) {
  let splitHolder = [];
  let splitArr = string.split("");
  while (splitArr.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numSplit; i++) {
      splitHolder[i] = splitHolder[i] === undefined
          ? [splitArr.shift()]
          : splitHolder[i].push(splitArr.shift());
      console.log(splitHolder);
    }
  }
}
```

Results for the console.log shows:

```
[ [ 'A' ] ]
[ [ 'A' ], [ 'B' ] ]
[ [ 'A' ], [ 'B' ], [ 'C' ] ]
```

which indicates the function is running okay at least on the first loop.  However on the second pass of the for loop after it is checked by the while.  I am getting this log:

```
[ 2, [ 'B' ], [ 'C' ] ]
[ 2, 2, [ 'C' ] ]
[ 2, 2, 2 ]
```

Which is very strange as I am still trying to push what is remaining of the array?  Where did the numeric 2 come from?

Initially thought it was a scoping issue but it wasn't as the let is scoped for the whole function.

Also tried the array reduce function but am still getting the same numeric 2.

Comment: `'ABCABCABC'.split('').sort().join('')`

Comment: `Array#push` returns the new length of the array, and you're doing `splitHolder[i] = splitHolder[i].push(...);` Just use an `if` statement like everybody else.

Comment: Thanks for the comment of @NiettheDarkAbsol pointing me to the right direction on the what is causing the appearance of the number 2.  It is indeed the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

`concat` returns a new array and `push` the new length of the array.

```js
function splitter(string, numSplit) {
    let splitHolder = [];
    let splitArr = string.split("");
    while (splitArr.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < numSplit; i++) {
            splitHolder[i] = splitHolder[i] === undefined
                ? [splitArr.shift()]
                : splitHolder[i].concat(splitArr.shift());
        }
    }
    return splitHolder;
}


console.log(splitter('ABCABCABC', 3));
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina.  Really missed that push return value.  Leaned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Array.push() return new length of the array after push

```
 let arr =['A', 'B']
```

when you will push into this array.

```
arr.push('C') // return 3 . i.e. length of the array.
```

I think you don't want to push into splitHolder but concatenate the first element of splitArr .

```
function splitter(string, numSplit) {
  let splitHolder = [];
  let splitArr = string.split("");

  while (!!splitArr.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numSplit; i++) {
      splitHolder[i] = (splitHolder[i] === undefined)
          ? [splitArr.shift()]
          : splitHolder[i].concat(splitArr.shift());
      console.log(splitHolder);
    }
  }
 return splitHolder;
}
```